# What is a good approach to solving tangram puzzles in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, declarative

I'm not sure if this best belongs here or in math but I figure I can get some pointers here about the code as well.
For an assignment I need to solve convex [Tangram puzzles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangram) using Prolog.

All puzzles and available pieces are defined as lists of vertices. For example:
    `puzzle(1,[(0,0),(4,0),(4,4),(0,4)])` represents a square puzzle and `piece(1,[(0,0),(4,0),(2,2)])` could be one of the large triangles.

I already have defined all 7 pieces with an id and a list of points and I think I should be able to write the proper code to iterate through these pieces and perform some operations on them. However, I'm not that insightful when it comes to geometry so I have no clue how I could determine which piece fits where on a puzzle simply based on its vertices.

Most of the assignments in this course are based on classic combinatorial problems such as Travelling Salesman. Are there any such problems involving convex shapes (or any kind of shape) that might inspire me to come up with a solution? I'm having a hard time finding online examples of declarative code that deals with shapes in this way. It would be very helpful if I knew what to look for.

I figure I can verify a solution is correct by checking if the outer borders of the puzzle are covered once and the inner ones (resulting from placing pieces) are covered twice. I could probably use this fact as a base case for some part of my solution. Other than that the best I can think of at the moment is brute forcing every piece into some unoccupied space between the borders of the puzzle till they fit.

Comment: Implementing the brute-force solution and then refactoring that using CLP(FD) predicates is often a good way of solving this kind of problems.

Comment: The design problem is to reduce the possible placements to a discrete (finite) search space.  Certain pieces have more symmetry than others, which might be helpful in reducing the size of the search space, but vertex location and orientation are initally constrained to a continuous set of values.  I like the idea of placing figures along the boundary, which leads to a sequence of boundaries of smaller area regions.  I'd thought about a "dissection" problem of other shapes in which a way to discretize the placement possibilities was more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to solve this problem should be detection of pieces' overlapping. By definition, if no overlapping occurs, each admissible placement will be a solution. Then, iterating piece' placement we should detect if any overlapping occurs.

Each shape can be represented as the union of the smallest triangles resulting from subdivision of unit grid. We have a total of 100 (4*5*5) small triangles.

Thus overlapping can easily be detected by intersection, when we have a proper translation of list of coords to list of small triangles.

For instance, numbering in ascending coords and clockwise, the `piece(1, [(0,0), (1,1), (2,0)])` becomes `[2, 3, 4, 7]`.

Rotating a shape clockwise of 90° around the origin it's easy, if we note that for each rotation: X'=Y and Y'=-X. The piece above, rotated 90° clockwise: piece(1, [(0,0), (1,-1), (0,-2)]). When normalized on Y: piece(1, [(0,2), (1,1), (0,0)]).

Determining which small triangles cover a shape can be done naively repeating the '[point in polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)' test for each small triangle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your explanation about rotating shapes and suggesting the point in polygon test helped me come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to solve the problem with pure Prolog, or can you use Constraint Programming as well?

If you can use CP, then take a look at this paper: [Perspectives on Logic-based Approaches for Reasoning
About Actions and Change](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~agostino.dovier/PAPERS/gelfond_06ott10.pdf). Section 6 describes how the authors solved tangram with CLP(FD).

Maybe the paper gives you an idea how to solve it even if you have to use pure Prolog, since constraints can be replaced by passive tests. The search will then take longer, though, since the search tree won't be pruned by the constraints.

I also remember that someone in a CLP course I took long ago used Gröbner bases to reason about geometry ("how to move a piano around a tight corner?"), although I'm not sure whether that would be applicable for solving tangrams.

I'm sorry if that's all a bit theoretical and advanced.